# How to untag all people in Photos

Tags: photos.app

I have had an ongoing problem, where Photos (on both my Mac and my iPhone) is not updating people. The message I get says something about quitting Photos and letting it update people in the background whilst being connected to power.

I have visited many forums and tried many different techniques, but I am still not having any luck after ***6 months!!!***.  I only have about 4,000 photos, so really wouldn't expect this process to take long.

I have decided, the best thing to do now is to literally untag everyone in my photos and start from scratch.  I am prepared to tag everybody individually if it really came to it, but what I would ideally like is for Photos to forget every person and start from scratch, asking me who each person is.

And there lies my question. How do I make Photos completely forget about a person. I have right clicked a person in my People library and selected "Remove this person from library". That does remove the person, but when I open a photo, that person is still tagged under their name.  I have tried rebuilding my library (CMD + option whilst launching Photos), but that just tries to re-tag everyone under the existing names.

How can I make Photos forget everyone and let me start again?